# WAR Validation Failed: org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.exception.DeploymentDescriptorLoadException: WEB-INF/web.xml

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-framework-beans

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8eAE1.png)this is error image.I am getting error and warning from spring tool suit when, I am creating mvc project. can someone please help me how to figure out from this issue?

suggestion and solution.  (WAR Validation Failed: org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.exception.DeploymentDescriptorLoadException: WEB-INF/web.xml)

Comment: The exception is not related to your project. Don't post images with error messages if they can be posted as text.

Comment: ok, but how can I resolve this issue?

Comment: If you have an idea how to resolve this issue you should add it to the question. Without details and the defined problem is not possible to find a solution.